# ¿Cómo generar un enlace de parámetros GET y habilitar botón?

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
$( function() {
    $("#id_categoria").change( function() {
        if ($(this).val() === "1") {
            $("#id_input").prop("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $("#id_input").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <select name='id_categoria' id='id_categoria'>
        <option value="1" selected>Materia</option>
        <option value="&materia?=php">PHP</option>
        <option value="&materia?=mysqli">MYSQLI</option>
    </select>
    
    <select name='id_categoria2' id='id_categoria'>
        <option value="1" selected>Total de preguntas</option>
        <option value="&limit?=50">50</option>
        <option value="&limit?=?=100">100</option>
    </select>

    <input id="id_input" type="submit" disabled>
</div>
```

Me gustaría poder generar un enlace automáticamente sin recargar pagina con las opciones de `option select` la idea es generar enlace automáticamente con parámetros GET, ejemplo:

```
example.com/quiz/quiz.php?materia?=php&limit?=?=100
```

Comment: No se escriben valores asi en HTML en option value="&limit?=50"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pepe.

Tendrias que aclarar un poco, como pretendes hacer lo y para que es. Ya que generar este enlace es posible con el formulario en si, indicando lo con HTML:

```
<form action="example.com/quiz/quiz.php" method="get">
```

Tambien tienes error en tu HTML, los elementos no pueden tener el mismo identificador, en tu caso se repite "id_categoria".
Entonces cuando vas a pulsar el boton submit se te generara petición con el metodo GET, no el metodo POST habitual de los formularios.

Por otro lado, podrias hacer un pequeños JavaScript, que te genera y guarda una variable global, que contenga un enlace. Por ejemplo que se genera cuando seleccionas un valor. Aqui te dejo un ejemplo completo, cuando cambias uno de los selectores te genera el enlace, lo guarda en una variable y ademas te la muestra:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <select name='materia' id='materia'>
                <option value="" selected>Materia</option>
                <option value="php">PHP</option>
                <option value="mysqli">MYSQLI</option>
            </select>

            <select name='limit' id='limit'>
                <option value="" selected>Total de preguntas</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>
                <option value="100">100</option>
            </select>

            <input id="id_input" type="submit" disabled>

            <span id="result">URL</span>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            "use strict";

            function generarEnlace() {
                let materia = sel1materia.options[sel1materia.selectedIndex].value;
                let limit = sel2limit.options[sel2limit.selectedIndex].value;

                enlaceGenerado = "http://example.com/quiz/quiz.php?materia=" + materia + "&limit=" + limit;
                result.innerText = enlaceGenerado;
                console.log(enlaceGenerado);
            }           

            let enlaceGenerado = "";
            let sel1materia = document.getElementById('materia');
            let sel2limit = document.getElementById('limit');            
            let result = document.getElementById('result');
            sel1materia.addEventListener('change', generarEnlace);
            sel2limit.addEventListener('change', generarEnlace);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```